# Dynamically loaded controls from Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

So this is more of a best practices question. I have a restful web api with a data access layer that is using EF6 and a web MVC project that sends DTOs via RestSharp to the API get what I need from the database.

What I'm running into is now I have a form that will have multiple (4-5) dropdown lists that need to be loaded dynamically from different tables on the database and it feels clunky to do them all as separate data calls. Any direction on best practices to approach this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice I am no expert on but the way I would do it would be to create a new single view model entity that combines all these, then add some business logic that can make all the calls to construct / deconstruct this model.